# Clear already visible notifications that belong to my app

Tags: java, android, push-notification

My app uses Firebase Cloud Messaging to show incoming push notifications. Notification payload sent to Fireboase by backend is like this:

```
{
  "to": "/topics/599_79",
  "priority": "high",
  "data": {
    "id_message": "209"
    "id_city": "599"
  }

  "notification" : {
      "body" : "New message test",
      "title" : "New message" 
      "click_action": "MESSAGE_DETAILS" 
    }
}
```

My app activity receives data via Intent Filter:

```
 <intent-filter>
     <action android:name="MESSAGE_DETAILS"/>
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
 </intent-filter>
```

It works fine. If my app is in background or not running, Firebase shows notification, on notification tap, Android starts activity corresponding to intent filter.

However, I also need implement functionality similar to Gmail - I need all notifications to be cleared atuomatically after user runs app with launcher icon.
So, how to clear notifications programatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put the below code in the `onCreate()` method of your launcher activity

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) 
getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notificationManager.cancelAll();
```